# Return type based on input type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I know there are similar questions, but I don't get it.

How can I configure the types to have `inputType` = `outputType` ?

```
public addReadableTime(message: PublicMsg | PrivateMsg): PublicMsg | PrivateMsg {
   message.displayTime = moment(message.lastModified).format('HH:mm');
   return message;
}

// ...

const publicMsg = this.addReadableTime(publicMsg);
```

> TS2322: Type 'PublicMsg | PrivateMsg' is not assignable to type 'PublicMsg'.   Property 'publicChannelMessageId' is missing in type 'PrivateMsg' but required in type 'PublicMsg'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like what you need is a generic method with a type constraint:

```
public addReadableTime<T extends PublicMsg | PrivateMsg>(message: T): T {
   message.displayTime = moment(message.lastModified).format('HH:mm');
   return message;
}

// ...
const publicMsg2 = this.addReadableTime(publicMsg);
```